# Slideshow plugin allowing animation between slideshow transitions

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Are there slideshow plugins allowing animation between slideshow transitions similar to the flash slideshow on this [page](http://www.ianwatt.ca/ActiveListings.php/Details/453/1280-richards-street-the-grace-residences-vancouver-bc#viewdetail)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is known as the "Ken Burns" effect. [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/) is a great plug-in for this.